# Python ffmpeg not working on heroku, no error but it just kind off freezes at that line

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg, discord.py

When I run the bot offline it just works but when i run it on the heroku server it doesn't. it prints the time right at the first time, then the bot connects to the channel and then it just freezes, i get no errors in the heroku logs, the bot just stays online. I've added the ffmpeg buildpack into the buildpacks in heroku and added ffmpeg to the requirements.txt. the time is also correct (i defined the time earlier using an other package) so it can asses the sound file but it just sort of freezes at the ffmep line and doesn't play the sound, and then doesn't print the time and doesn't disconnect.

```
voice = await channel.connect()
print(time)
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f'sounds/{arg}.mp3'))
print(time)
sleep(time)
await voice.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The problem is you also need to install **libopus**. To do this:

- Enter your Heroku page.
- Go to Settings.
- Click Add Buildpack in Buildpacks.
- Type `https://github.com/codeinteger6/heroku-buildpack-libopus.git` in Enter Buildpack URL section.
- Deploy your app again.

I hope this will work.